# NumberPickerPreference for androidx-preference kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, androidx

I'm currently using the new androidx-preference library for my new project and I'm creating a number picker preference for my settings page in my app. 
Is there a guide that show how I can create a number picker dialog preference for it?